# powershell script removing files from the first of the month, instead of keeping them

Tags: powershell

```
$RollingYear = (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)
$Rolling30Days = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

#Clean-Up Old Backup Files
Get-ChildItem 'D:\Server_Backup\' | ForEach-Object {
    if ( $_.LastWriteTime.AddDays(-365) -lt $RollingYear) {
        Write-Host "I want to remove files older than a year"
        Remove-Item
    } Elseif ( $_.LastWriteTime.AddDays(-30) -lt $Rolling30Days -and $_.LastWriteTime.Date -ne (Get-Date -Year $_.LastWriteTime.Year, -Month $_.LastWriteTime.Month -Day 1)) {
        Write-Host "I want to remove files older than 1 month, but not the first of the month"
        Remove-Item
    } Else {
        Write-Host 'Nothing to remove'
    }
}
```

This should keep files from the first of the month of anything older than 30 days and remove the rest.  Currently it is removing the 1st of the month and keeping the rest.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: the way you calc the 1st of the LWT month leaves the current time in the datetime object. that can throw off your comparison. have you tried wrapping that calc in `().Date` to get midnight of that day?

Comment: also, your `Remove-Item` lines need a "what to remove" value. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your logic confused me [*blush*], so i rewrote it using day counts instead of datetime comparisons.

```
$SourceDir = $env:TEMP

$Today = (Get-Date).Date
$YearInDays = 365
$MonthInDays = 30

#Clean-Up Old Backup Files
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        $DaysOld = ($Today - $_.LastWriteTime).Days
        if ($DaysOld -gt $YearInDays)
            {
            ''
            'LWT = {0}' -f $_.LastWriteTime
            'File age in days = {0}' -f $DaysOld
            Write-Host "I want to remove files older than a year"

            Remove-Item $_.FullName -WhatIf
            }
            Elseif ($DaysOld -gt $MonthInDays -and
                $_.LastWriteTime.Day -ne 1)
            {
            ''
            'LWT = {0}' -f $_.LastWriteTime
            'File age in days = {0}' -f $DaysOld
            Write-Host "I want to remove files older than 1 month, but not the first of the month"

            Remove-Item $_.FullName -WhatIf
            }
            Else
            {
            ''
            'LWT = {0}' -f $_.LastWriteTime
            'File age in days = {0}' -f $DaysOld
            Write-Host 'Nothing to remove'
            }
    }
```

output ...

```
LWT = 2015-11-03 6:54:02 PM
File age in days = 1276
I want to remove files older than a year
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\Temp\FXSAPIDebugLogFile.txt".

LWT = 2019-03-04 12:45:30 PM
File age in days = 59
I want to remove files older than 1 month, but not the first of the month
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\Temp\Itunes_Default-Rating_Set.ps1_2019-05-03.log".

LWT = 2019-03-01 12:44:23 PM
File age in days = 62
Nothing to remove

LWT = 2015-11-03 9:35:03 PM
File age in days = 1276
I want to remove files older than a year
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\Temp\qtsingleapp-fmlast-93b-1-lockfile".

LWT = 2019-05-03 6:43:11 AM
File age in days = 0
Nothing to remove
```

Comment: Lee, I will test this out.  My logic confused me a bit too, but yours looks like it is spot on.

Comment: @Shenanigator - i often get date comparisons backwards since older is less than newer .. but i think of older in terms of _age_ & that gives the reverse result. [*blush*] so i finally started doing date comparisons in terms of age since that is how i always think of it. [*grin*]